# How do I change spacing between marginnote and body in twosided document?

Tags: geometry, double-sided, marginpar

By default in a twosided document the marginnotes appear in the outer margins of every page. The spacing between the body and the margin note varies from even to odd pages. What is the reasons for this behavior and how can I avoid it? I want to have the same space between marginnote and text body no matter on what side the note appears. Here is what I tried but fixing the marginparsep like this apparently does not do the trick as the space/distance between note and body are clearly changing. What is wrong here?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]\marginpar{p. 5} \lipsum[5-9]\marginpar{p. 6}
\lipsum[10-14]\marginpar{p. 7}
\end{document}
```

There has to be simple solution for this I feel.

Comment: With \marginpar{\hfill p. 6} maybe ?

Comment: Of course I look for a global solution.

Comment: replace marginpar by marginnote

Comment: If you add the [showframe] option to geometry, you will see that everything is fine.  Unless you expect \marginpar to be \raggedright on odd pages and \raggedleft of even pages.

Comment: That is exactly what I expected to be the standard. The text body should define where the ragged of the marginnote is – that is how I felt anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with marginote it's Ok

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{marginnote}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-5]\marginnote{p. 5} \lipsum[5-9]\marginnote{p. 6}
  \lipsum[10-14]\marginnote{p. 7}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: That is it: it had to be simple. Thanks a lot.